# "first" not really meaning the ordinal first

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

FIRST has many definitions, including:

- before *any other* in time, order, or importance
- before doing other things

alternatively:

- in preference to something else : SOONER

I am seeking use examples of the last two definitions -- "first" as a relative term, rather than THE ordinal first

"Head-first" is the best example I can provide. Dive into a pool head-first, and actually your hands will precede the head, so the head is technically not "the first." It's used as a relative term (head-first vs feet-first), not a literal term where your head will be the first body part to contact the water .

Another (weaker) example might be asking someone if they floss first or brush first? Or perhaps at a restaurant, while ordering, the waiter might ask "should I bring the soup first?" (as opposed to with your entree) although you've already been served drinks and some bread.

Thank you for your responses.

[definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first#examples)

Comment: Are you asking about the concept of "what came before" or an expression?  Chicken, egg?

Comment: That is one of the definitions of *first* - *before **another** in time* (m-w)

Comment: @livresque hi, I'm not looking for historical or past events, I'm seeking concrete examples of using "first" in the context of a comparison rather than specifically THE first. If that helps :)

Comment: @DjinTonic yes exactly, now I'm trying to think of examples or common usages of that specific definition of the word "first"

Comment: We use that meaning all the time. "Who arrived first, Bob or Sue?" // There are two main ways we enter the water, head first and feet first. It's orientation.  *Arms first* is ambiguous.

Comment: @DjinTonic On that example, I disagree. You've specifically reduced the set of people, so among that group, one of them did arrive ordinal #1 (first). It's a tricky question which is why I'm having trouble giving good examples.

Comment: @ExactaBox You might be overthinking the "head first" example, which is like the Bob / Sue example. "Head first" has implicitly limited the options to "head first" or "feet first", so you actually are indicating between two options which came first.

Answer (score 1):

An example may be [First Among Equals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primus_inter_pares#:%7E:text=The%20Prime%20Minister%20of%20the%20United%20Kingdom%20has%20frequently%20been,of%20Commons%20and%20other%20matters.) Which has been applied to the British Prime Minister. The Wikipedia article under the link has a number of other interesting applications of the same concept including the Archbishop of Canterbury.

It also contains the useful definition

> Bearing higher status and various additional powers while remaining still merely equal to their peers in important senses.